# Can Colorbox stop popup if target url is not available

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have an anchor which link to a resource, and I apply colorbox on it.

Is it possible to make Colorbox not to show the pop up window if the target url returns http error codes such as '404 not available'?

intreted

I want avoid writing external checks which result in loading the same target twice.

**Edit**

I checked the API, but no callback is for after loading before rendering:

```
onComplete  Callback that fires right after loaded content is displayed.
onCleanup   Callback that fires at the start of the close process.
```

Comment: Using Ajax to check the content first. Ajax provide methods or variables to read the response code (is actually intreted).

Comment: As far as I know there is now way. By the way the response code '404' means 'Page not found' ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that ColorBox opens *before* loading the content, so colorbox itself doesn't know the request status.

I fear that all you can do is an Ajax HEAD request before invoking colorbox, which should be pretty fast, and then caching the request status.

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var self = $(this);
    var href = self.attr('href');
    if(self.data('success') == 'success') {
        $.colorbox({href:href});
    } else if (self.data('success') == 'error') {
        return;
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            type: "HEAD",
            async: true,
            url: href,
            success: function(message,text,response){
                $.colorbox({href:href});
                self.data('success', 'success');
            },
            error: function() {
                self.data('success', 'error');
            }
        });
    }
});​
```

fiddle to test here: http://jsfiddle.net/JS9Sc/

Comment: If you are going to handle the ajax request yourself, save the data and send it to colorbox instead of making 2 requests.  $.colorbox({html:data}).